# Populate css grid with images

Tags: javascript, image

I have a 100 image with the same size that I want to put in a CSS grid.

the folder consists of:

seperate-0.png
seperate-1.png
seperate-2.png
seperate-3.png

and so on..

the css is as following.

```
html,
body,
.grid-container {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(7, 1fr);
    gap: 0px 0px;
    grid-template-areas: ". . . . . . ." ". . . . . . ." ". . . . . . ." ". . . . . . ." ". . . . . . ." ". . . . . . ." ". . . . . . .";
}


/* For presentation only, no need to copy the code below */

.grid-container * {
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: relative;
}

.grid-container *:after {
    content: attr(class);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

the html:

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-container">img 1 here</div>
</div>
```

How can I populate this with the images of the folder.
I think I need to generate divs with the contents of the directory.

Comment: your need to add html, and output the dom for the images, css on its own cant do what your after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML**

*Added a new class grid-container-parent*

```
<div class="grid-container grid-container-parent">
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var imagePath="./image/seperate-";
var numberOfImage=100;

var parentDIV = document.getElementsByClassName("grid-container-parent")[0];

for(var i=0;i<numberOfImage;i++){
    var tempDIV= document.createElement('div');
    tempDIV.setAttribute('class','grid-container');
    var innerHTML= `<img src='`+(imagePath+i)+`.png'></img>`
    tempDIV.innerHTML=innerHTML;
    parentDIV.appendChild(tempDIV);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a loop from 1 to 100 to create and insert `img` with the appropriate `src`.
Like so

```js
const gridContainer = document.querySelector('.grid-container');
for (let i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
  const img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = `path-to-img/seperate-${i}.png`;
  gridContainer.append(img);
}
```

Note that I've changed your HTML to

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <!-- images will come here -->
</div>
```